# Updating DB depending on value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of objects:

```
object_id -- active -- tarif_id
1            1         5
2            0         6
3            1         19
```

And I have a table of tarifs:

```
tarif_id -- expire_date
5           2014-01-01
6           2014-05-01
19          2015-12-11
```

Is it possible to write an SQL that will check all `object's tarif_id's` expire dates with the `Date.NOW` and if `Date.Now` is more, then set `object's active` status to `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE tblObject 
INNER JOIN tbltarifs ON tblObject.tarif_id = tbltarifs.tarif_id
SET tblObject.active = 0
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y') > DATE_FORMAT(expire_date,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: If `expire_date` is defined as a `DATE` then using `date_format` is wrong. You should compare dates not strings. The date `2010-01-30` will be considered "bigger" than `2015-01-01` when compared as a string with that format.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.  You're looking for the `UPDATE` function.

```
UPDATE ObjectsTable
SET active = 0
WHERE [tarif_id] IN (
        SELECT [tarif_id]
        FROM TarifTable
        WHERE [expiredate] < DATE.Now --or whatever you are using to get the current date
        )
```